# Publish native artifact with id embedding platform information

Tags: gradle

I’m trying to publish a C++ library to a maven repository using the maven nar artifact naming convention, something like mylib-amd64-windows-msvc.zip. I tried to access targetPlatform from the publishing block but it is not accessible from the block.

```
publishing {
    publications {
        maven(MavenPublication) {
            group = ‘com.mycom.myproj’
            artifactId “myproj-${targetPlatform.architecture}-${targetPlatform.operatingSystem}”
            version ‘1.0’
        }
    }
}
```

I get the following error:

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'list'.

  > Exception thrown while executing model rule: PublishingPluginRules#publishing(ExtensionContainer)
  >   Could not get unknown property 'targetPlatform' for object of type org.gradle.api.publish.maven.internal.publication.DefaultMavenPublication.

Comment: Have you studied https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/native_software.html? What about `"${component.baseName}${targetPlatform.name}"` as suggested in https://discuss.gradle.org/t/get-targetplatform-from-current-tasks/8775/4?

Comment: @MarkusPscheidt: The problem is while targetPlatform is accessible in binaries, it does not seem to be accessible in the publishing block.